# Checking if user, then checking if member

Tags: php, mysqli

So I'm checking whether the person accessing the page is a user then redirecting them to the signup page if they're not.

Then I'm checking whether the user is a member ( paid subscription ) if not then redirect to the user page.

The redirecting for the **non users** work
But with the code below, noone can get access to the membership page because of the `is_member` check

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include('connect.php');
ob_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("**********");
}
else
{
    $username =$_SESSION['username']  ;
}
$check = $mysqli->query("SELECT is_Member FROM users WHERE username = $username");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
$isMember = $row['is_member'];
if ($isMember == 0){
    header("*************");
}
```

*is_member is either a 1 or a 0: **1 meaning they are a member***

**Connect file:**

```
<?php
$servername = "*****";
$user = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "******";

$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $user, $password, $dbname); //used to connect to the database

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
     die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: many syntax errors. quotes issue, mixing MySQL APIs and not bothering checking for errors, anywhere.

Comment: ask the guy below, he submitted an answer and got an upvote for it too. I'm out of this loop.

Comment: Fair enough, whats the point in commenting then?

Comment: because, 9 times out of 10, I place an answer and I get to fix it for an hour after that.

Comment: plus this `connect.php` is a Pandora's box.

Comment: A Pandora's box means; I don't know what's in that "box" and it may bite me in the *"you know what"* if I don't get to see what's in there ;-)

Comment: So are you telling me to make an edit where I show the connect.php?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` that... well "will" fail you. And the other guy didn't catch that as I stated above; you're mixing MySQL APIs.

Comment: for all I know `connect.php` could be using `mysql_` or PDO to connect with.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is mysql_fetch_assoc, literally have no idea how I don't spot these things. Been looking at it for an hour

Comment: so use this $isMember= $check->fetch_assoc();?

Comment: that's one way, yes ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
WHERE username = $username");
```

If the variable is a string (i.e.: "john", then it should be wrapped in quotes:

```
WHERE username = '$username'");
```

Then you're using a `mysql_` function `mysql_fetch_assoc` which does not intermix with any other MySQL API than its own.

It must read as `mysqli_fetch_assoc` with the added `i` for the function.

Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

You should also add `exit;` after each header, otherwise you code may want to continue executing.

Another thing; your code is prone to an SQL injection. It's best that you use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your check will always come up false because there is not `is_member` value, it is a typo.  Replace this:

`$isMember = $row['is_member'];`

with this:

`$isMember = $row['is_Member'];`

Also your `else` statement should probably include more

Comment: probably 0.01 % of the problem.

Comment: it's is_member in the database

Comment: Well then this is incorrect: `SELECT is_Member FROM users WHERE username = $username`

Comment: The problem is, I was using sql syntax instead of sqli